# Ignore certain state transitions in Workflow

Tags: 7, workflows

Is it possible to disable certain state transitions with Workflow?

I have 4 states: Pending, Approved, Denied, and Urgent. A node goes directly to Pending when saved, where an editor can either Approve or Deny it. Deny kicks you back to Pending. Urgent happens when an editor hasn't reviewed a node in 7 days. Then it can also be Approved or Denied.

As Workflow is now, you can transition from any one state to any other state. But I have no use for going from, say, Approved back to any state, or from Denied directly to Approved. Is there a way to disable the transitions I don't need to use?